# Retrieving Version Name from Google Play Developer API

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

Is there a way to resolve the **VersionName** of a specific release of an app using the VersionCode?

Everything I found on the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) is using to VersionCodes. I'm trying to build a listing of releases including VersionNames of various applications.

Comment: Are you looking for `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` ?

Comment: @NicolasSimon Yes, but I do not have access to physical manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, but I may be wrong. There is versionCode which is used by Google Play for the formal release number, which must be incremented with each release, then you have versionName, which is a string and can be anything. So, there is an inherrent disconnect between the two, and therefore no enforced relationship.